# Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "dane-srv" while powering up instance (volume error)

Tags: openstack

I have an instance that does not want to power on. I keep getting the errors below:

Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "dane-srv", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: Volume device not found at [u'/dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.21.30:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-c58a6541-01cf-41ce-b58a-91e026b86089-lun-1'].].

When I ran the command below I get an empty volume list. However on horizon the volumes are visible but some are showing error status or available.

All instances with volumes attached are not able to power up and unable to attach or detach volumes as well.

```
root@controller:~# cinder list
+----+--------+------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| ID | Status | Name | Size | Volume Type | Bootable | Attached to |
+----+--------+------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
+----+--------+------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+

Errors in /var/log/cinder/cinder-volume.log
2021-06-28 14:03:16.048 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.targets.tgt [req-274640b3-6431-4944-95d1-a2518bc4f64d - - - - -] Failed recovery attempt to create iscsi backing lun for Volume ID:iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-c58a6541-01cf-41ce-b58a-91e026b86089: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: sudo cinder-rootwrap /etc/cinder/rootwrap.conf tgtadm --lld iscsi --op new --mode logicalunit --tid 17 --lun 1 -b /dev/cinder-volumes/volume-c58a6541-01cf-41ce-b58a-91e026b86089
Exit code: 22
Stdout: u''
Stderr: u'tgtadm: invalid request\n'
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager [req-274640b3-6431-4944-95d1-a2518bc4f64d - - - - -] Failed to re-export volume, setting to ERROR.
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/manager.py", line 461, in init_host
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     self.driver.ensure_export(ctxt, volume)
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/drivers/lvm.py", line 821, in ensure_export
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     self.target_driver.ensure_export(context, volume, volume_path)
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/iscsi.py", line 261, in ensure_export
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     old_name=None, **portals_config)
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/utils.py", line 796, in _wrapper
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     return r.call(f, *args, **kwargs)
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/retrying.py", line 206, in call
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     return attempt.get(self._wrap_exception)
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/retrying.py", line 247, in get
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/retrying.py", line 200, in call
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cinder/volume/targets/tgt.py", line 243, in create_iscsi_target
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager     raise exception.ISCSITargetCreateFailed(volume_id=vol_id)
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager ISCSITargetCreateFailed: Failed to create iscsi target for volume volume-c58a6541-01cf-41ce-b58a-91e026b86089.
2021-06-28 14:03:16.813 32116 ERROR cinder.volume.manager
```

Comment: Talk a little bit about your setup. Which volume drivers are you using (looks like LVM-iSCSI, but please confirm), how did you set up this cloud. Obviously you need to investigate the target software; are there problems with tgtd, can you use the target client (often tgtadm, but that depends on your configuration).

Comment: @berndbausch thank you for your response. Yes we are using lvm-iscsi

[lvm]
volume_driver = cinder.volume.drivers.lvm.LVMVolumeDriver
volume_group = cinder-volumes
iscsi_protocol = iscsi
iscsi_helper = tgtadm

Comment: Good. Now run `tgtadm` and explore the target.

Comment: @berndbausch I have tried the command below:
tgtadm --lld iscsi --op show --mode target

I can see the target but openstack volume show <volume id> shows an error state

also openstack volume list is empty